# Delete rows with blank values in one particular column

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I am working on a large dataset, with some rows with NAs and others with blanks:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:7),                                   
         home_pc = c("","CB4 2DT", "NE5 7TH", "BY5 8IB", "DH4 6PB","MP9 7GH","KN4 5GH"),               
         start_pc = c(NA,"Home", "FC5 7YH","Home", "CB3 5TH", "BV6 5PB",NA),               
         end_pc = c(NA,"CB5 4FG","Home","","Home","",NA))
```

How do I remove the NAs and blanks in one go (in the start_pc and end_pc columns)?  I have in the past used:

```
df<- df[-which(is.na(df$start_pc)), ]
```

... to remove the NAs - is there a similar command to remove the blanks?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
 df[!(is.na(df$start_pc) | df$start_pc==""), ]
```

Comment: `|` is an or-operator and `!` inverts. Hence, the command displays all rows, which are *not* b) NA or b) equal to "".

Comment: Wouldn't this code remove entire rows, as opposed to just consolidating them by removing empty values?

Comment: This is what I found works as well. I had a dataset where I wanted to remove the rows where I was missing data from the column. Executing this with my own data frame and assign the value to the new data frame did what I expected.

Answer (score 34):

It is the same construct - simply test for empty strings rather than `NA`:

Try this:

```
df <- df[-which(df$start_pc == ""), ]
```

In fact, looking at your code, you don't need the `which`, but use the negation instead, so you can simplify it to:

```
df <- df[!(df$start_pc == ""), ]
df <- df[!is.na(df$start_pc), ]
```

And, of course, you can combine these two statements as follows:

```
df <- df[!(df$start_pc == "" | is.na(df$start_pc)), ]
```

And simplify it even further with `with`:

```
df <- with(df, df[!(start_pc == "" | is.na(start_pc)), ])
```

You can also test for non-zero string length using `nzchar`.

```
df <- with(df, df[!(nzchar(start_pc) | is.na(start_pc)), ])
```

---

*Disclaimer: I didn't test any of this code. Please let me know if there are syntax errors anywhere*

Comment: @richiecotton Thanks for the edit. `nzchar` is a neat way of testing for non-zero length, and I didnt' know about it.

Comment: no of these solutions work in my case! `df<-structure(list(vars = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", "b", "v", 
"d", "e", "s", "ds"), class = "factor"), '1' = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), '2' = c(NA, 0.9, NA, NA, NA), 
    '3' = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("vars", 
"1", "2", "3"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 23):

An elegant solution with dplyr would be:

```
df %>%
  # recode empty strings "" by NAs
  na_if("") %>%
  # remove NAs
  na.omit
```

Comment: Very elegant solution and simple :)

Comment: Indeed, esp. for someone who is only occasionally confronted with R code, clear and simple is a welcome sight. Wish more posts were like that!

Answer (score 8):

An easy approach would be making all the blank cells `NA` and only keeping complete cases. You might also look for `na.omit` examples. It is a widely discussed topic.

```
df[df==""]<-NA
df<-df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternative solution can be to remove the rows with blanks in one variable:

```
df <- subset(df, VAR != "")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.